# Create a dictionary from a file and adding values

Tags: python, string, dictionary, counter

*Updating as my post from earlier was deleted and am getting errors.

I must open a text file and import it into a dictionary. The text file contains 2 pieces of info: product IDs and a string of customer reviews. My goal is to read through customer feedback provided and count the number of times a good or bad keyword appears in a review for each product ID. Note, some product reviews include the same good/bad word twice.

My end goal is to be able to display the count of good and bad words that appear for each product. I will then add the good and bad key words together to show total key words. I have the following that a user helped me put together but am getting stuck on the counter. Also, I had originally created a `class`, but was told this was not necessary.

My code is giving me a `KeyError` when trying to go through the for loop in the dictionary to count each instance of good and bad words. 
Also, it does not appear that my counter is set up properly

My question is, how do I properly create a counter to total the number of good and bad words for each product ID? The counter must take into account repeat words.

```
dictionary = {}
good = ("perfect", "nice")
bad = ("broken", "wrong", "terrible")     
with open("products.txt","r") as products:
    for line in products:
        p = line.split(',',1)[0]
        f = line.split(',',1)[1]
        dictionary[p] = v.lower()
print(products)

for c in dictionary:
    for word in dictionary[c].f().split():
        if word in good:
            dictionary[c]+=1
        if word in bad:
            dictionary[c]+=1

for k in dictionary.keys():
    print(dictionary[k].productID,dictionary[k].good,dictionary[k].bad)
```

The first few lines of the text file read as follows:

4321,Item was broken when received. Terrible product.
5432,Nice product.
6321,I received the wrong item. Now Im being told I can't return the wrong item. How terrible!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You have told us what you want to do (though it's a bit confusing) but you haven't asked a question. What is wrong with the code you're showing us? In what way does it fail to do what you want?

Comment: ...you've now added an error message to your question. Please _always, **always** include error messages when you ask questions here_. They're there for a _reason_, and we shouldn't have to ask for them. Now, instead of just telling us "My code is giving me a KeyError when...", what is the _exact, complete traceback_? "When I try to..." isn't clear clear; a line number and traceback with exact code snippets gives us _much_ more information.

Comment: Sorry, trying to updated based on your feedback. Hopefully my edits help clarify.

Comment: can you show an extract of your `products.txt` ?

Comment: Can't be specific without more information (such as the whole traceback), but one can avoid `KeyError`s by handling `KeyError`s in a `try`/`except KeyError:` or by checking with `if word in dictionary: …`.

Comment: @moctarjallo the file is in the following format:

4321,Item was broken when received. Terrible product.
5432,Nice product. 
6321,I received the wrong item. Now Im being told I can't return the wrong item. How terrible!

Comment: @PythonNoob you need to show that text file (not just describe it) and also show your exact error traceback. For that you can edit your question and add what is necessary..

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understood your needs but, is this what you are looking for?

```
import re
dictionary = {}
good = ("perfect", "nice" )
bad = ("broken", "wrong", "terrible")     
with open("products.txt","r") as products:
    for line in products:
        p = line.split(',',1)[0]
        f = line.split(',',1)[1]
        f = re.sub('\?|\.|\!|\/|\;|\:|\´|\`|\*|\¨|\%|\(|\)|\&|\$|\=|\+|\,|\[|\]\'\"', '', f) #remove pontuation
        dictionary[p] = {'text':f.lower(),'good':0,'bad':0}

for c in dictionary:
    for word in dictionary[c]['text'].split():
        if word in good:
            dictionary[c]['good'] += 1
        if word in bad:
            dictionary[c]['bad'] += 1

for k in dictionary.keys():
    print("id = %s, text = %s, good = %i, bad = %i" % (k,dictionary[k]['text'],dictionary[k]['good'],dictionary[k]['bad']))
```

Comment: This does a lot of what im looking for. I appreciate it and am sorry for the confusion on my wording. While I haven't learned the import function, it seems to work fine. The only thing Im stuck on is how to isolate the total count for each good and bad word per product ID. I am looking to take each products total good count and subtract it from the bad count if that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

So for what I am understanding your file may have more than one entry by product
E.g

4321,Item was broken when received Terrible product 
5432,Nice product.
6321,I received the wrong item Now Im being told I can't return the wrong item How terrible
4321,Nice product.
and so you expect this results:

id:4321 good:1 bad = 2 good-bad:-1
id:5432 good:1 bad = 0 good-bad:1
...

if this is your case, you can use the following code (basically the same with a few adaptaions)

```
import re
dictionary = {}
good = ("perfect", "nice" )
bad = ("broken", "wrong", "terrible")     
with open("products.txt","r") as products:
    for line in products:
        p = line.split(',',1)[0]
        f = line.split(',',1)[1]
        f = re.sub('\?|\.|\!|\/|\;|\:|\´|\`|\*|\¨|\%|\(|\)|\&|\$|\=|\+|\,|\[|\]\'\"', '', f) #remove pontuation
        if p in dictionary:        
            dictionary[p]['text'] += f.lower()
        else:            
            dictionary[p] = {'text':f.lower(),'good':0,'bad':0}

for c in dictionary:
    for word in dictionary[c]['text'].split():
        if word in good:
            dictionary[c]['good'] += 1
        if word in bad:
            dictionary[c]['bad'] += 1

for k in dictionary.keys():
    print("id = %s, text = %s, good = %i, bad = %i, good-bad =%i" % (k,dictionary[k]['text'],dictionary[k]['good'],dictionary[k]['bad'],dictionary[k]['good']-dictionary[k]['bad']))
```

Comment: Each product ID actually only appears once! Its just the positive or negative words within the reviews that may appear more than once. Separate question based on what you provided because I am unfamiliar with the import function. Is it then possible to write a separate line in addition to your end print line to only show the (good-bad) values as in integar for each product id? Could I create some type of list?

Comment: For the first part of your question I did not understand what I missed in my first code. That code will count the number of times any word on good or bad list will appear in  the comment. I am not sure what I missed. 
On your second question you can add the following line in the loop
print("id = %s, good-bad =%i" % (k,dictionary[k]['good']-dictionary[k]['bad']))
which will print only the good-bad result
Or you can create another dictionary with only the ID and the good-bad data by adding the following line on the loop
dic_good_bad[k] = dictionary[k]['good']-dictionary[k]['bad']

Comment: Im not sure that you missed anything! While it wasn't stated in my initial question, as I reviewed what you provided I became curious whether it was possible to take the word counts and put them into a list. I will have to wait until tomorrow to run this code when im in school, but I think you covered what I was asking!! I really appreciate your help and wish I could borrow your brain :)